# Load xml data from web API to dataset and then get relational data from datatables to new data table

Tags: c#, xml

I am totally new to C# development and first time posting here so forgive me if i am posting in wrong place or sound silly

I need to pull xml data from web API i have manage to do this

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("webURLhere");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer Tokenvalue");
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(newStreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(reader);
```

i am stuck at this point on how to actually utilise this data in the StreamReader

after giving up on using Streamreader i downloaded xml file that's returned looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response status="ok">
<submissions>
    <submission>
        <id>12345</id>
        <timestamp>2020-06-02 09:20:49</timestamp>
        <user_agent>Mozilla/5.0</user_agent>
        <remote_addr>111.111.111.11</remote_addr>
        <payment_status></payment_status>
        <latitude>321</latitude>
        <longitude>123</longitude>
        <read>1</read>
        <data>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>91388567</field>
                <value>2723</value>
                <flat_value>2723</flat_value>
                <label>URN</label>
                <type>number</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>1</field>
                <value>
                    <XML_Serializer_Tag>disclaimer</XML_Serializer_Tag>
                </value>
                <flat_value>disclaimer</flat_value>
                <label>Checkbox</label>
                <type>checkbox</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>2</field>
                <value>12345</value>
                <flat_value>12345</flat_value>
                <label>ID</label>
                <type>number</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>3</field>
                <value>Name</value>
                <flat_value>Name</flat_value>
                <label>Name</label>
                <type>text</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>4</field>
                <value>email@email.com</value>
                <flat_value>email.email.com</flat_value>
                <label>Email</label>
                <type>email</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>5</field>
                <value>filelink</value>
                <flat_value>filelink</flat_value>
                <label>OL1</label>
                <type>file</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>6</field>
                <value>filelink</value>
                <flat_value>filelink</flat_value>
                <label>DC1</label>
                <type>file</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <field>7</field>
                <value>filelink</value>
                <flat_value>filelink</flat_value>
                <label>DC2</label>
                <type>file</type>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
        </data>
    </submission>
</submissions>
<total>1</total>
<pages>1</pages>
<pretty_field_id>4321</pretty_field_id>
```

I have managed to get this xml data from a local file into a dataset by doing this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\All.XML", XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

DataSet visualizer shows me the data, i can see the relationships within the dataset by looking at dataset in debug mode. I am also able to work on each table individually by doing this

```
dt1 = ds.Tables[2];
```

but cannont create a relationship between tables.

I need to pull data from submission, data and XML_Serializer_Tag tables based on ralationship into one datagridview but i have not been able to get anywhere all day today. Please help....

***** Edit ********

ok managed to do this finally. here's my code, posting it here becuase it took me ages to figure it out and unlimited amount of Googling didn't give me a result.

```
        var submissions = xEle.Descendants("submission");
        int Srno = 0;
        foreach (var sub in submissions)
        {
            int rowId = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowId];
            var sub_data = xEle.Descendants("submission").ElementAt(Srno).Descendants("data").Descendants("XML_Serializer_Tag");
            foreach (var SData in sub_data)
            {
                row.Cells["id"].Value = sub.Element("id").Value;
                row.Cells["timestamp"].Value = sub.Element("timestamp").Value;
                row.Cells["Srno"].Value = Srno + 1;
                row.Cells[SData.Element("label").Value].Value = SData.Element("value").Value;
            }
            Srno++;
```

This returns data for each row from submission and then loads everything related to submission from data.XML_Serializer_Tag into datagridviewrow by row, used Srno to generate row number in datagridview.

only thing left now is how do i get data from "response" i need "total" and "pages"

Also please do let me know if i have gone off track here and could have done this differently

Comment: With complicated xml files the ReadXml will give fractured data that is useless. The data cannot be recombined to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your entire question, but it will help you with using the response stream from the WebRequest.

```
TextReader reader = new StringReader( new StreamReader( request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream() ).ReadToEnd() );
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml( reader, XmlReadMode.Auto );
```

Alternatively, you could try:

```
ds.ReadXml( request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), XmlReadMode.Auto );
```

Though I prefer to break things apart (like using the TextReader) to help simplify readability and troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you try your solutions?  The results will give you fracture data the is in tables that make no sense.

Comment: Yes i was able to see the data in each table in datagrid view by doing this

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];

Answer (score 0):

Try xml serialization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
            Response response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            int Srno = 1;
            foreach (var sub in response.submission)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Row_number = '{0}', Id = '{1}', Date = '{2}'",  Srno++, sub.id, sub.timestamp); 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("response")]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlAttribute("status")]
        public string status { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("submissions")]
        [XmlArrayItem("submission")]
        public List<Submission> submission { get; set; }
        public int total { get;set;}
        public int pages { get;set;}
        public int pretty_field_id { get;set;}
    }
    public class Submission
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        private DateTime _timestamp { get; set; }

        public string timestamp
        {
            get { return _timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }
            set { _timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
        }

        public string user_agent { get; set; }
        public string remote_addr { get; set; }
        public string payment_status { get; set; }
        public int latitude { get; set; }
        public int longitude { get; set; }
        public int read { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("data")]
        [XmlArrayItem("XML_Serializer_Tag")]
        public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
    }
    public class Tag
    {
        public int field { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("value")]
        public string _value { get; set; }
        public string flat_value { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed reply, as i mentioned in my question i am totally new to using xml or development in C#. i am not sure how i can use this to get the result i want. ideally i want to insert each row from xml into and SQL server table. I can insert rows in SQL server just need to know how i will loop through all the rows so i get one row with data from each xml node.

Comment: The rows are in the deserialize class as a list :  public List<Submission> submission { get; set; }  There are many way of parsing xml.  I use all of them.  In this case from the structure of the data I though serialize was the best way of going.  I can use xml linq to get each row from xml,  but didn't know what data you needed and the format so I chose serialize and parsed everything.  So use response.submission.Select(x => ...... (or a loop).

Comment: i am totally lost on how to use the code you gave me above, so i found this 

                XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
            var submissions = xEle.Descendants("submission");
            int Srno = 0;
             foreach (var sub in submissions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Row_number = " + Srno++ + " " + sub.Element("id").Value + ", " + sub.Element("timestamp").Value);

            }

which is listing all rows from submission, i want field, label and value from data for each submissions along side it.

Comment: There are lots of different ways of parsing an xml in c#.  Your code that you posted is using linq xml which I use very often.  My code use serialize and the data is all in the "response" variable.  To get each submission you can use the for loop : foreach(Submission submission in response.submission)

Comment: I updated my post, i have managed to get the result i wanted, thats one row with data from submission table and corresponding all rows from data table.

Comment: Do you need more help?

Comment: if you dont mind, how do i access the "total" and "pages" from reponse table?

Thanks for your help

Comment: response.total and response.pages